# Google Analytics (G4A) attaching user properties

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to attach user properties to track specific groups for their user sessions. But when I create a comparison my field doesn't exist on the users.

I am using the Vue2 and using this npm package: vue-gtag, using gtag.set({key: value}). I set up Google Tag Manager and in the Preview mode, I see the key being set. But how do I access these analytics in the report view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use to attach user properties using the `vue-gtag` package and access them in Google Analytics 4 (G4A) report view:

1. Attach user properties using `vue-gtag`:

```js
// Import the vue-gtag package
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag';

// Initialize VueGtag with your GA measurement ID
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: {
    id: 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID',
    params: {
      send_page_view: false, // Set to true if you want to track page views
    },
  },
});
```

2. Set user properties when needed:

```js
// Somewhere in your Vue component
this.$gtag.set({
  user_properties: {
    custom_property_key: 'custom_property_value',
  },
});
```

3. Access user properties in Google Analytics report view:

- Open your Google Analytics 4 property.
- Navigate to the "Reports" section.
- In the left sidebar, click on "Events" under the "Reports" section.
- You can explore various event reports that might contain your custom user property data. You might need to create custom events or parameters to capture and visualize the data effectively.

Remember that it might take some time for the data to populate in your reports after setting user properties. Also, ensure that you're using the correct property and view in your Google Analytics account.

Note: Google Analytics 4 provides more flexibility in event tracking and user properties compared to Universal Analytics, but the interface and terminology might differ slightly. Always refer to the latest Google Analytics documentation for any updates.